# SQL to fetch the result on the basis of the column value with value having the priorities

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union

I am trying to write the SQL to get the below result:

Rules:

- Priority IS BY PlanType (STO->MTO->LTO)
- Same taskIds can exist against the multiple PlanType

---

1. Fetch all the taskId with PlanType AS STO.
2. Fetch all the taskId with PlanType AS MTO which are not present with PlanType AS STO already.
3. Fetch all the taskId with PlanType AS LTO which are not present with PlanType AS MTO already.

---

Below are the DDL/import SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE FTASK (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    taskId VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
    PLANTYPE VARCHAR2 (100) 
);


INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (1,'T1','STO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (2,'T2','STO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (3,'T3','STO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (4,'T4','MTO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (5,'T5','MTO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (6,'T2','LTO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (7,'T1','LTO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (8,'T5','LTO');
INSERT INTO FTASK (ID,TASKID,PLANTYPE) VALUES (9,'T3','MTO');
```

Expecting below result:

[image: result]

I tried using UNION and INTERSECT.
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Your question is tagged Oracle, but the sample code is not compatible with Oracle -- it does not allow inserting multiple rows using `VALUES`.

Comment: Thanks Gorden, Corrected. Due to the DBeaver export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`.  Your types are in alphabetic order, so that fact can be used:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by taskid order by plantype desc) as seqnum
      from ftask t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can modify the `order by` to use a `case` expression if in the real problem the types are not alphabetical.  However, the above can make use of an index on `(taskid, plantype desc)`.

The above allows you to get all columns.  If you only have the three columns, you can also use aggregation pretty easily:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by plantype desc) as id,
      taskid,
      max(plantype) as plantype
from ftask
group by taskid;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's (rather verbose) way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=900ced30c23bb58ada6e97a365e0e0ec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Considering the performance when assuming to have 10 Million records in the FTask and the query needs to be run once  in a day, what do you suggest ? The 1st SQL is working good for me. Thanks

Comment: @Vaibs . . . 10 million records isn't very much.  I would imagine that either version would complete in at most a few tens of seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I am evaluating both of them now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gordon's answer, or you could also use row number with a proper `CASE` expression

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT f.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TASKID
                                   ORDER BY CASE PLANTYPE WHEN 'LTO' THEN 1
                                                          WHEN 'MTO' THEN 2
                                                          WHEN 'STO' THEN 3 END DESC) rn
    FROM FTASK f
)

SELECT ID, TASKID, PLANTYPE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, That make sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This. I think its perfect for you.**
Try from online: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7b597/1

```
  SELECT id, TASKID, PLANTYPE
    FROM (SELECT id,
                 TASKID,
                 PLANTYPE,
                 CASE
                    WHEN PLANTYPE = 'STO' THEN 1
                    WHEN PLANTYPE = 'MTO' THEN 2
                    WHEN PLANTYPE = 'LTO' THEN 3
                 END
                    order_by
            FROM (SELECT id, TASKID, PLANTYPE
                    FROM FTASK
                   WHERE PLANTYPE = 'STO'
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT id, TASKID, PLANTYPE
                    FROM FTASK
                   WHERE     PLANTYPE = 'MTO'
                         AND TASKID NOT IN (SELECT TASKID
                                              FROM FTASK
                                             WHERE PLANTYPE = 'STO')
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT id, TASKID, PLANTYPE
                    FROM FTASK
                   WHERE     PLANTYPE = 'LTO'
                         AND TASKID NOT IN (SELECT TASKID
                                              FROM FTASK
                                             WHERE PLANTYPE = 'MTO')))
ORDER BY order_by, TASKID;
```